# My scrollbar didn't work in mozilla firefox browser,it works only in chrome browser

Tags: html, css

I want to show scroll bar for all browsers.But my scroll didn't appear like chrome's scroll.It showing like a normal scroll.But, I created radius scroll bar with beautiful design.I don't want to use jquery and javascript.How can I do that to show for all browser?

**CSS**

```
.scrollbar {
  width: 620px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.force-overflow {
  min-height: 350px;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #464242;
}

#style-1::-moz-scrollbar-track {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #464242;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #464242;
}

#style-1::-moz-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #464242;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #85b59d;
}

#style-1::-moz-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #85b59d;
}

.scrollbar2 {
  width: 620px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- image block -->
<div class="image-main-block scrollbar " id="style-1">
  <div class="force-overflow">
    <img src="../css/images/flower.jpg" alt="" height="130" width="195"></img>
    <img src="../css/images/img2.jpg" alt="" height="130" width="195"></img>
    <img src="../css/images/im3.jpg" alt="" height="130" width="195"></img>
    <img src="../css/images/im4.jpg" alt="" height="130" width="195" class="image"></img>
    <img src="../css/images/flower.jpg" alt="" height="130" width="195" class="image"></img>
    <img src="../css/images/img2.jpg" alt="" height="130" width="195" class="image"></img>
    <img src="../css/images/im4.jpg" alt="" height="130" width="195" class="image"></img>
    <img src="../css/images/flower.jpg" alt="" height="130" width="195" class="image"></img>
    <img src="../css/images/img2.jpg" alt="" height="130" width="195" class="image"></img>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of image block -->
```

Comment: The problem is that there is no such thing as `::-moz-scrollbar-track`, because this is a webkit-only feature. See https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/